# Missing iOS 9.0 simulator in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build MobileVLCKit and at the end of the compilation appears:

```
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos9.0" cannot be located.
```

I tried to add device with iOS 9.0 manualy, but only 9.1 or 8.x are available.
How can I install 9.0 SDK manualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install the 9.0 SDK.  You have the 9.1 SDK.  Just use the "iphoneos" SDK.  It will work fine for targeting iOS 9.0 or iOS 8.x deployment targets.